# How to open boot camp Windows 7 machine in Hyper-V?

Tags: windows

I currently have a user with a boot camp unit, it has a Windows 7 Pro machine that I would like to extract and open in Hyper-V.  I am not sure how to do this or if it is possible.  Not sure how to ask the question but the end result would be this Windows 7 Pro machine would be running on a Hyper-V 2008 Enterprise x64 server.  I am completely familiar with Hyper-V but I am an Apple novice and am looking for specific assistance in getting the Boot Camp Windows 7 machine running properly in Hyper-V (latest version) (all updates and patches are installed).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft offers a free conversion utility that is designed to move/copy a physical system to a virtualized environment, specifically Hyper-V: Disk2VHD.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415